# Privilégio de vincular usuários a perguntas

Tags: novo-recurso

Seria legal ter um privilégio, onde possamos **marcar usuários do SO**.

O fluxo de perguntas é muito grande, e às vezes, aparecem questões muito bacanas, de grande poder de discussão, que poderíamos marcar nossos amigos para ver como uma forma de chamar para discutir.

A ideia de ser um **privilégio**, é evitar as pessoas ficarem marcando os usuários mais conhecidos em tudo.

Poderia até ter um limite, tipo da **sinalização**.

Comment: Você diz, usuários do site ou não usuários?

Comment: Do SOpt, no nosso caso, e como você "entrou" na comunidade Exchange (pelo que eu entendo dessa plataforma). Eu achei algo bacana, quero te marcar, e ponho @Maniero na pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

Eu acho que até poderia ter algo *opt-in* seletivo (cada um escolhe o mínimo de reputação que aceita o *ping* e ter uma *whitelist* ou *blacklist*), mas [decidiram não ter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116582/140010).

Comment: Acho que é porque levam para o lado da "obrigação" em responder, e não é esse o intuito. Seria realmente algo em comum entre usuários, que marque o colega no tipo "olha isso", "não fique sem ver", etc... que pena !

Comment: @RBZ, para contornar essa limitação, eu: (a) mando no [chat **Estouro de Pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) marcando a pessoa que conheça ou, (b) envio mensagens privadas através de outros aplicativos/outras redes sociais; claro, isso limita a eu ter acesso a essas pessoas nas outras redes sociais, o que não costumo fazer aqui no SOpt, com exceção da rede LinkedIn

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O (a) funciona para usuários que costumam entrar no chat, não sei quanto tempo, mas imagino que pelo menos 1 vez por semana, depois não marca mais. O (b) é legal porque exige um esforço um pouco maior e você pode bloquear quem abusar desse privilégio :) Por falar nisso muita gente ainda não está nas minhas redes.

Answer (score 5):

Eu pessoalmente acho que seria bastante invasivo e vai levar o site totalmente pro lado de **suporte técnico free** (o que por alguns já é visto assim), não estou falando que você faria, mas isso se tornaria comum na comunidade.

Eu acredito que no momento já temos ferramentas razoáveis para isto, que são os FEEDs:

[image: icones feed, rss, atom, xml]

O problema é que mesmo muitos trabalhando com WEB, ainda sim muitas vezes não entendem como funciona os feeds e acabam por não aproveitar isto. Pra resumir os feeds funcionam assim, você "segue" um feed, usando um plugin ou navegador com suporte ou um serviço de terceiros online (antigamente o google tinha, não sei se tem mais), então as novas perguntas no site em uma tag especifica que você segue iriam aparecendo pra ti e você responde se dispor de tempo e interesse.

---

A minha opinião é que centralizar perguntas em pessoas especificas é tirar a oportunidade de outros responderem, existe muita gente boa oculta por ai, assim como existem muitas pessoas que respondem coisas ruins e vivem de "suporte técnico free" pra crescer dentro do site, pra resumir eu peço que olhe pra comunidade e não para as pessoas, eu sei que vai ter muita gente boa que você já conhece, que você gostaria de *pingar*, mas a oportunidade tem que ser o mais igual possível e o suporte técnico é algo que já existe em fóruns a anos e se isso funcionasse bem fóruns seriam um sucesso e o StackOverflow não.

Comment: Entendi sim, e concordo com você em tudo. Principalmente na questão de dar oportunidades aos outros e até poderia gerar certa "panelinha" dos "melhores" nos assuntos. A ideia era algo mais voltado não para responder e sim pelo assunto ser de interesse daquelas pessoa. Por exemplo, cada pessoa tem uma preferência sobre um assunto, gosta de coisas mais complexas, o outro gosta de uma coisa mais bem elaborada, de um tópico com assuntos que dá para ser bem mais elaborado do que só uma resposta técnica. Eu vejo que tem alguns usuários que usam o SO como ferramenta de trabalho até.

Comment: Mas também sou novo em programação, no SO, e no decorrer do tempo vejo essa outra perspectiva como vocês vêem.

Comment: @RBZ por isso sugeri o feed, se for de interesse os proprios respondedores seguem as tags de assuntos que mais lhes interessam, eu por exemplo sigo duas tags (bem especifica).

Answer (score 5):

Há várias formas bem simples de fazer isso:

1. Procure uma postagem da pessoa que você quer chamar a atenção e deixe um comentário lá com um link e uma explicaçãozinha simples do que você espera dela. Por exemplo: "*@fulano Acho que você poderia contribuir também com [essa questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6962/132)*". Você pode deixar comentários onde quiser [tão logo atinja 50 pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
2. Use a [nossa sala de chat: Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha). Para participar lá, só são necessários 15 pontos de reputação. Entretanto, você só irá conseguir notificar quem estiver online ou que esteve lá recentemente.
3. Muitos usuários (nem todos) deixam em seus perfis aqui no SOpt, endereços de e-mail, twitter, facebook, whatsapp, blog, etc. Se quiser entrar em contato com alguém, esse é um meio a ser tentado. Para acessar o perfil de alguém neste site, basta clicar no nome dele(a). Não é necessária nenhuma reputação aqui para fazer isso (aliás, nem precisa estar logado ou ter cadastro no site).
4. Todas as perguntas e respostas do site têm um botão "compartilhar" logo abaixo delas. Por exemplo, abaixo da sua pergunta, para mim aparece isso:

   <kbd>[image: botão compartilhar]</kbd>

   Sei que a interface de usuário poderia ter sido melhor concebida e que para quem não está acostumado com o site, isso não parece um botão. Mas acredite em mim, isso é um botão sim! Clique nesse botão e ele te dará um link para você compartilhar com quem você quiser pelos meios que você achar melhor. Inclusive, se o link que você compartilhou for acessado por muitas pessoas, você pode ganhar as seguintes medalhas:

   - [image: Anunciador] -  25 endereços IP diferentes acessaram um link que você compartilhou.
   - [image: Incentivadr] - 300 endereços IP diferentes acessaram um link que você compartilhou.
   - [image: Jornalista] - 1000 endereços IP diferentes acessaram um link que você compartilhou.

   Ao clicar no botão "compartilhar", o número do seu usuário é colocado no final do link gerado exatamente para que os acessos efetuados nele possam ser contabilizados para você. Por exemplo, eu cliquei no botão "compartilhar" da sua pergunta e o link que foi produzido para mim foi "*https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6962/132*". Nesse link, o 6962 é o número da sua pergunta e o 132 é o meu número de usuário.

   Dessa forma, você pode pegar esse link e compartilhá-lo com seus amigos no facebook, twitter, whatsapp, blog, e-mail, etc, a vontade. Não é exigida nenhuma reputação para isso. Aliás, você nem precisa estar logado ou mesmo cadastrado no site, isso está disponível até mesmo para usuários anônimos. O único porém é que se você não estiver logado no site (ou nem mesmo estiver cadastrado), nesse caso o número do seu usuário não é colocado no link gerado.

Observe que todas essas formas de interação já são possíveis hoje. Você pode utilizá-las livremente (desde que não abuse, ninguém gosta de gente chata enchendo o saco) e inclusive eu vejo muitos usuários utilizando esses mecanismos sem problema nenhum (inclusive eu). Assim sendo, não acho necessário criar-se mais um mecanismo para fazer isso.

Comment: Acharia legal se tivesse um inbox ou algo do tipo. Não é questão de compartilhar, é questão de marcar uma pessoa que "gosta" daquele assunto e não a pessoa que "entende" do assunto. Claro que seria utilizado para ambos, mas aí se fazem os filtros  nas opções do usuário. Acho que o SO pode chegar a um ponto que a pessoa pode "enjoar" de certos tipos de perguntas, ou até da própria ferramenta. Existem muitas formas de compartilhar, mas sempre depende de algo externo ou um "esqueminha" (chat). A ideia não é transformar numa rede social, jamais, mas ter algo que seja um "curtir" e levar ao amigo.

Comment: @RBZ Há um inbox com duas categorias na barra superior do site. Um é o ícone da bandeja e o o outro o do troféu. O do troféu tem notificações de medalhas e pontos de reputação recebidos. O da bandeja tem comentários e edições de terceiros recebidos em perguntas e respostas, respostas recebidas em perguntas, respostas de chat, avisos de eleições para moderadores em sites da SE que você participa, avisos de expiração de recompensas oferecidas, e talvez mais algumas outras coisas. Talvez uma sugestão seja no sentido de mudar a categorização, embora eu não veja como isso poderia prosperar.

Comment: Me parece que o que ele quer é bem diferente da *inbox* de hoje, o que ele quer é realmente "pingar" um usuário de preferencia dele, o que no máximo podemos fazer comentando em postagens que o usuário já participou ou em chat (se ele usar), mas a eficiência disto comparado ao pedido dele é de um grande esforço, eu pessoalmente como já disse acho acho extremamente invasivo.